# index out of range array subscript

Tags: arrays, swift, subscript

I try to learn S.O.L.I.D principle and i have a problem when I want to subscript an array, it show an error message. but when I try to subscript with arc4random_uniform the error message not show up. can anyone show me what it wrong?

> Thread: 1 fatal error: Index out of range

this is my code in Item Class

```
class Item: NSObject {
var imageName: String
var label: String

init(imageName: String, label: String) {
    self.imageName = imageName
    self.label = label

    super.init()
}

convenience init(list: Bool = false) {
    if list {
        let imageList = ["milada-vigerova", "david-rodrigo", "quran"]
        let labelList = ["Fiqih", "Hadist", "Tafsir"]

        // The sortImage and sort label, the error show up
        let sortImageName = imageList[imageList.count]
        let sortLabel = labelList[labelList.count]

        self.init(imageName: sortImageName, label: sortLabel)
    } else {
        self.init(imageName: "", label: "")
    }
  }
}
```

update question. this is another error in appDelegate while fixing the subscript

```
let itemStore = ItemStore()
    let homeController = window?.rootViewController as! HomeController
    homeController.itemStore = itemStore
```

this is my itemStore class

```
class ItemStore {
var allItems = [Item]()

@discardableResult func createItem() -> Item {
    let newItem = Item(list: true)
    allItems.append(newItem)

    return newItem
}

init() {
    for _ in 0..<3 {
        createItem()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did the answers addressed your original problem? If yes, please accept one and ask another question for the new problem you've run into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**imageList** have 3 items, and lastest item at index 2, similar with **labelList** , modify code at two lines:

```
// The sortImage and sort label, the error show up
let sortImageName = imageList[imageList.count - 1]
let sortLabel = labelList[labelList.count - 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Index in an array starts at 0 so a 3 element array has indexes 0,1 and 2 and `count` = 3 so to access the last item of an array using `count` you need to do `[someArray.count -1]`

```
if list {
    let imageList = ["milada-vigerova", "david-rodrigo", "quran"]
    let labelList = ["Fiqih", "Hadist", "Tafsir"]

    // The sortImage and sort label, the error show up
    let sortImageName = imageList[imageList.count - 1]
    let sortLabel = labelList[labelList.count - 1]

...
```

Notice that `arc4random_uniform(n)` returns a value between 0 and `n-1` so doing `arc4random_uniform(imageList.count)` for instance will work perfectly

Comment: Answer this question at same time. >.<

Comment: It's mean that you and me answer this question at same time :)

Comment: @ChuongTran there is another error Thread 1 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION in my app delegate let itemStore = ItemStore()
        let homeController = window?.rootViewController as! HomeController
        homeController.itemStore = itemStore. can you help me a little bit

Comment: @ferryawijayanto Can you update your question and show more code about your issue? It's easier for guys can help you.